# Speeding up event handling in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I'm building an interactive graph visualization tool using d3.  I have written a function called `showNeighbors(nodeIndex)` which visually highlights the neighbors of a given node.  Consider the following two snippets of code which call this function:

1. Show the neighbors of a node clicked by the user:

   ```
   svg.selectAll(".node")
   .on("click", function(d, i) { 
       showNeighbors(i); 
       d3.event.stopPropagation(); 
   });
   ```
2. Show the neighbors of each node in sequence:

   ```
   svg.select("body")
   .on("keydown", function() {
       var i = 0;
       setInterval(function() {
           showNeighbors(i);
           i++;
       }, 100);
   });
   ```

I have noticed that for large graphs (5000+ nodes), the first event handler is very slow while the second is very fast: if you click on a node then you have to wait a few seconds for the `showNeighbors` function to be called, but if you press a key then the nodes start highlighting in sequence as fast as you could want.

What I have learned from this (and other experiments) is that there is a considerable amount of overhead in locating the node that needs to handle the click event: the only difference between the two examples is that the argument passed to the `showNeighbors` function is event driven in the first snippet but deterministic in the second.

So my question is: can I somehow speed up the first snippet?  I am willing to make some compromises if necessary; for instance, it would be OK if the click event is handled very quickly for, say, 100 nodes that I choose even if it is very slow for the rest.  Any ideas?

---

A complete, working example illustrating the lag in handling click events (added later):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

nodeData = [];
linkData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    nodeData.push({"name": i});

var index;

for(var i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3000));

        if(i != index)
            linkData.push({"source": i, "target": index});
    }

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodeData)
    .links(linkData);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

force.start();

force.on("end", function() {
    var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(linkData)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke", "black");

    var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodeData)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .style("fill", "black")
        .on("click", function(d, i) {
            someFunction(i);
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
        });

    d3.select("body")
        .on("keydown", function() {
            var i = 0;
            setInterval(function() {
                someFunction(i);
                i++;
            }, 100);
    });

    links
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodes
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});

function someFunction(node) {
    d3.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(e, j) { return node == j; })
        .style("fill", "LightBlue");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example please? Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Can you show us the showNeighbors function?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I added a complete example as you requested.

Comment: @Moogs The details of the `showNeighbors` function aren't actually important since the lag all happens before the function is even executed.  I changed it to something simpler in the detailed example that I just added.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. At least I'm not noticing any appreciable lag when clicking on the nodes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm also running Chrome, and I timed it at about 3 seconds between the click and the response.  When I went up to 5000 nodes the lag increased to 10 seconds.  Am I the only one?

Comment: I'm running Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (Developer Build) Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). I'm getting a tiny lag of maybe 100 milliseconds (which I'm guessing is because of it checking every single node in the handler), but certainly nothing like 3 seconds.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Well, I'm perplexed.  I'm running OSX - could that make a difference? One of my colleagues (also OSX) reports the same lag times.

Comment: Yes, that could certainly make a difference. Have you tried other browsers to see if that changes anything? At least it doesn't look like there's anything that could be done on the D3 side.

Comment: I am experiencing the same lag of 3 seconds running Chrome 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) on OS X.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I just tried it on Firefox (still OSX) and there was no noticeable lag.  So it seems that whatever the problem is it is specific to Chrome on OSX.   Weird...  Any idea if there are any sort of Chrome settings which might improve performance?

Comment: Actually I should qualify that - even in Firefox the lag still exists for some nodes in the middle of the blob, and I'm also seeing it in some of the examples which originally motivated this question.  Perhaps there is some way to restrict the collection of nodes to which the event handler listens?

Comment: I was going to recommend using a quadtree to partition your nodes. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214 However I've found that in Mac OSX on Chrome the sample is very laggy and slow -- in the past it was mooth like butter! So I'm thinking there is something wrong with the latest Chrome. But something like a quadtree should help.

Comment: This example might be more on point and seems to work well. http://bl.ocks.org/llb4ll/8709363